# alternative way of "multiple" inheritance

Tags: c#-4.0

i have a scenario as follow:

```
    public class A : class B
    {
         public SomeMethodA()
         {
              //.... do some logics here
              SomeMethodB();
         }

         private SomeMethodB()
         {
              //.... do some logics here
         }

    }

class B : class C
```

---

```
class X : class Y
{
     public SomeMethodA()
     {
          //.... do some logics here
          SomeMethodB();
     }

     private SomeMethodB()
     {
          //.... do some logics here
     }
}

class Y : class Z
```

class A has the exact same method as class X does.  Now the question is: How do I combine this method in centralised so that my code has DRY (don't repeat yourself) without modifying/touching class Y, Z and class B, C?   Class B, C, Y, and Z are our legacy code and we are NOT trying to alter/modify these classes.

any thoughts?

Comment: I'm having trouble picturing what you're asking, and I don't see any multiple inheritance demonstrated here.  Can you post some actual code demonstrating the situation?

Comment: what is the access level of class B, C? And your question is not clear, do you want to add new methods with same name in classes X and A without disturbing Y,Z,B and C?

Comment: Class A and Class X have the exact same two methods... How do i avoid DRY?

Comment: Is the code in SomeMethodA/SomeMethodB identical across your classes?

Comment: I'm not sure why this got down voted. It looks like a very reasonable request for a suggestion on how to do inheritance.

Comment: @Derek.. - thanks.. i'm not too sure why.. I'm gettig stuck with my project but now I'm thinking to use it for interview question...

Answer (score 3):

Since you edited and made it more clear. I believe this will work. Just create a common class in which X and A will inherit.

```
public abstract class Common
{
     public SomeMethodA()
     {
          //.... do some logics here
          SomeMethodB();
     }

     private SomeMethodB()
     {
          //.... do some logics here
     }
}

public class A : Common { /* some other methods */ }
public class B : A { /* some other methods */ } //B inherits A
public class C : B { /* some other methods */ } //C inherits B

public class X : Common { /* some other methods */ }
public class Y : X { /* some other methods */ } //Y inherits Z
public class Z : Y { /* some other methods */ } //Z inherits Y
```

**2ND EDIT:**

```
public class Common
{
     public void SomeMethodA()
     {
          //.... do some logics here
          SomeMethodB();
     }

     private void SomeMethodB()
     {
          //.... do some logics here
     }
}
```

Then in both classes A and X, do something like this:

```
public void SomeMethod() {
    Common c = new Common();
    c.SomeMethodA();
}
```

Comment: how does it work changing class B inherits from class A ? class A will be used as a code-behind in the aspx page.   and Also as i mentioned class B, C , Y and Z are legacy. We are trying NOT to alter them.

Comment: @user384080 - Is Class A and X your bottom level code? (e.g. are you going backwards with the alphabet for labeling?)

Is it like this, from the top down: C -> B -> A?

Comment: @user384080 - If that's the case, C# doesn't support multiple inheritance, because its bad design. If you want to eliminate redundant code and not modify the legacy code, what you'll have to do is create a separate class, like class Common above (without the abstract).

_See the edited section in the answer above._
So, you're basically calling a method from another class, instead of having A and X inheriting it.